# How to write a spec where a map has a key which has heterogeneous content based on another key

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm pretty sure I need a multi-spec, which works. But I am unsure how to say that a key value which is a vector can contain heterogeneous maps.

My is my source data I want to spec:

```
(def int-attr { :type "int" :validations [{ :min 0 } { :max 100 }] })
(def string-attr { :type "string" :validations [{ :presence true }] })
```

It is the `validations` key I am having problems with, depending on the `type` key, `"int"` or `"string"`, I want a different spec in the `validations` key.

I'm pretty sure I have to use a `multi-spec`. Here is what I have tried:

```
(defmulti attribute-type :type)
(defmethod attribute-type "string" [a] ::string-validations)
(defmethod attribute-type "int" [a] ::int-validations)

;; how to say this is a vector of int-min-validation, or int-max-validation etc.
;; (s/+ ...) and (s/or ...) maybe?
(s/def ::int-validations (...) 
(s/def ::string-validations (...)

;; not sure how to incorporate these...    
(s/def ::int-min-validation (s/keys :req-un [::min]))
(s/def ::int-max-validation (s/keys :req-un [::max]))
(s/def ::string-presence-validation (s/keys :req-un [::presence])) 

(s/def ::attribute (s/multi-spec attribute-type ::type))

(s/explain ::attribute int-attr)
(s/explain ::attribute string-attr)
```

Comment: The specs you have are constructed in a bit of a strange way; if you could give an example of actual data you're trying to spec, it will make your intent clearer and easier to help.

Comment: The actual data is at the top, `int-attr` and `string-attr`.

Comment: Ok I see -- I was thrown off by the fact that what you seem to want to validate using spec are, in fact, attributes for *further validation*. Perhaps `int-attr` and `string-attr` will be used in some other part of your system where that type of validation makes sense, but it just looks very strange here. For example, if you wanted to validate an integer between 0 and 100, using spec, you'd just use the built-in `(s/int-in 0 101)` . `:presence` is a bit strange, and even the use of the word `validations` seem to indicate an equating of "spec" with "validation", which is not really accurate.

Comment: Oh, yes, the idea of validations and presence is domain specific and not anything to do with spec itself, I can see how this might have confused matters. It is a bit meta.

Answer (score 5):

Use *namespaced keywords* to allow same key, but spec the value using two different specs, namely `int/validations` and `string/validations`. To allow a vector that contains maps, a good option is to use `s/coll-of`.

```
(def int-attr { :type "int" :validations [{ :min 0 } { :max 100 }] })
(def string-attr { :type "string" :validations [{ :presence true }] })

(defmulti attribute-type :type)
(defmethod attribute-type "string" [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::type :string/validations]))
(defmethod attribute-type "int" [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::type :int/validations]))

(s/def :int/validations (s/coll-of :int/validation))
(s/def :string/validations (s/coll-of :string/presence))

(s/def :int/validation (s/keys :opt-un [:int/min :int/max]))
(s/def :int/min number?)
(s/def :int/max number?)
(s/def :string/presence (s/keys :req-un [::presence]))

(s/def ::attribute (s/multi-spec attribute-type ::type))

(s/explain ::attribute int-attr)    ;; => Success!
(s/explain ::attribute string-attr) ;; => Success!
```